# Globally installed node not found (Ubuntu 18.04)

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, command-line, sequelize.js

I actually installed `sequelize` and `sequelize-cli` but when I try to run it, the name cannot be found by `npx`. I've been trying a lot (changing PATH and NODE_PATH, reinstalling nodejs, trying absolute and relative paths....)

Now I get this:

> ole@messerbill:~$ echo $NODE_PATH
>
> /home/ole/.npm/lib/node_modules
>
> ole@messerbill:~$ npx sequelize-cli migration:generate --name change-app
>
> Programm konnte nicht gefunden werden: sequelize-cli
>
> ole@messerbill:~$ node -v
>
> v12.14.0
>
> ole@messerbill:~$ npm -v
>
> 6.13.4
>
> ole@messerbill:~$ npx -v
>
> 6.13.4

I am kind of desperate right now since I have no idea what to do...

**Edit:**
When I remove everything except `/usr/bin` from `$PATH` it works, but then i cannot use other programs like `nano` anymore. If I add multiple Paths it is again not working....

Comment: Have you tried installing it using npm instead of npx?

Comment: @PrabhjotSinghKainth how should i do this? I'd have to set an absolute path to the `sequelize-cli`